# Having trouble getting my if/else statement to render to another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am having problems using my if/else statement in React.js. Currently I am trying to have my program use an if/else statement to render to another program using the `useNavigate` hook with React Router. I only have one statement to see if when the answers are selected they render to another component.

*Test Case*

Description. After filling in the user survey, when the user hits submit the user will be sent to a specific page dedicated to their specific health needs.

Step 1): The user fills in the questions form

Expectation: the user fills in the form and it is shown which answers the user selected.

Actual: The user fills in the form and you can see the answers selected.

Step 2): The user then hits submit, and then with the users answers the page is then rendered to another page dedicated for that users health.

Expectation:  The user is rendered/taken to another page to look over there exercise options.

Actual: Nothing happens, or I get some sort of unexpected token error.

*Errors Exceptions*
I keep getting the error:
[Intervention] Slow network is detected. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5636954674692096 for more details. Fallback font will be used while loading: chrome-extension://liecbddmkiiihnedobmlmillhodjkdmb/fonts/CircularXXWeb-Book.woff2, which I have tried restarting my computer but that didn't help any, would this affect my code?

In my code I tried using an if/else and a switch statement, that would explain the zombie code.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Introduction from './components/introduction';
import Questions from './components/beginning';
import Male from './components/questions';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function App() {
  return (
    //Revisit <Route path="/questions" element= {<Male />} /> for Readability!!
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path= "/" element={<Introduction />} />
        <Route path="/beginning" element= {<Questions  />} />
        <Route path="/personalExercise" element={<personalExercise/>} />
        <Route path="/questions" element= {<Male />} /> 
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(<App />)
```

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function Questions(props) {
    const navigate = useNavigate()
    const[formData, setFormData] = useState({
        gender: "", 
        userAge: "", 
        goals:"", 
    });

    function handleChange(event) {
       const { name, value, type, checked } = event.target;
       setFormData(prevFormData => {
        return {
            ...prevFormData,
            [name]: type === 'checkbox' ? checked : value 
        };
       });
    }

    function handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault()
        navigate(getPath())
    };

    const getPath = () => {
        if(formData.gender === "male" && formData.userAge === "Young" && formData.goals === "active"){
            return navigate("/beginning")
        }
        // switch (formData) {
        //     case { gender: "male", userAge: "young", goals: "active" }: return navigate("../beginning");
        //     break;
        //     default:
        //        return navigate("/beginning")
        // }
    }
 
    return (
        <>
        <header>Questions</header>

        <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <fieldset>
            <legend>What was your gender at birth</legend>
                <input 
                type='radio'
                id = 'male'
                name = 'gender' 
                value = 'male'
                checked={formData.gender === "male"}
                onChange={handleChange}
                />
                <label htmlFor="male"> Male </label>
                <br />

                <input 
                type='radio'
                id='female'
                name='gender'
                value = 'female' 
                checked={formData.gender === "female"}
                onChange={handleChange}
                />
                <label htmlFor="female"> Female </label>
                <br />
            </fieldset>

                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>How old are you?</legend>

                        <input 
                        type='radio'
                        id="young"
                        name="userAge"
                        value="young"
                        checked={formData.userAge === "young"}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        />
                        <label htmlFor="young"> 18-28 </label>
                        <br />

                        <input 
                        type='radio'
                        id="middleAged"
                        name="userAge"
                        value="middleAged"
                        checked={formData.userAge === "middleAged"}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        />
                        <label htmlFor="middleAged"> 29-39 </label>
                        <br />

                        <input 
                        type='radio'
                        id="older"
                        name="userAge"
                        value="older"
                        checked={formData.userAge === "older"}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        />
                        <label htmlFor="older"> 40-50 </label>
                        <br />

                        <input 
                        type='radio'
                        id="senior"
                        name="userAge"
                        value="senior"
                        checked={formData.userAge === "senior"}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        />
                        <label htmlFor="senior"> 51+ </label>
                        <br />
                    </fieldset>
                    <br />

                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>What kind of fitness would you prefer?</legend>

                        <input 
                        type="radio"
                        id="active"
                        name="goals"
                        value="active"
                        checked = {formData.goals === "active"}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        />
                        <label htmlFor='active'>To stay active!</label>
                        <br />

                        <input
                        type="radio"
                        id="weight"
                        name="goals"
                        value= "weight"
                        checked = {formData.goals === "weight"}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        />
                        <label htmlFor="weight"> To loose weight</label>
                    </fieldset>
                    <br />

                    <button>Submit</button>
                    </Form>


                </>
    )
}
```

```
import React from 'react';
import {NavLink} from 'react-router-dom'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'

export default function beginning() {
    return (
        <>
        <p>Before beginning, would you mind entering some info about yourself? This information
            is used to help understand what kind of exercises suit you and lets the app know how 
            it can fit the 30 min sessions in your day! 
        </p>
        <p>If you would like to skip the questionnaire and dive right into exercising, so you 
            can personally select what you want as your exercise, that is also an excellent
            choice! </p>
            <NavLink to="/questions">
            <button>Take Questionnaire</button>
            </NavLink>
            <NavLink to="/exercise">
            <button>Skip Questionnaire</button>
            </NavLink>
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: I do not think case can accept Object as a value

Comment: That already has been commented out. @Rajesh

Answer (score 1):

In your function `getPath()` you are returning the navigate function itself to navigate function. I think that is something which is triggering the error. Rather you can just call the `getPath()` function and remove the return keyword inside the `if` condition. If your condition  is `true` it will navigate to the desired page or `else` nothing happens if the condition is not satisfied.

```
function handleSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  getPath();
};
const getPath = () => {
  if (formData.gender === "male" && formData.userAge === "Young" && formData.goals === "active") {
    navigate("/beginning");
  }
}
```